# Blue flash on touch for Android .apk

Tags: android, css, html, apk

I am working on an Android app using HTML5 and building the .apk with Adobe PhoneGap Build.

Every time I touch the screen, it flashes blue. It looks like a light blue  with opacity 0.6 or so app am wondering if it is text selection, but I don't know why; I even have -webkit-user-select set to none.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have paint flashing enabled.  In Safari Dev Tools, there is a paintbrush (think thin liner paintbrush) in the top right, next to print and the <> icons.  In Chrome, it's under the rendering tab.

When this is active, it will flash when you touch things.

Comment: Where is the rendering tab?

Comment: Hi Seth...the rendering tab is in Dev Tools,as a tab in the Console Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently `body { cursor: pointer }` does this.